# Binary Tree Search Node Method using recursion JAVA

Tags: java

Hi this is a sample tree

```
---------e
-------d----g
----b------f--t
---a--c--------z
```

so if my node is a string class. and I am trying to find f. I need to start searching for all the possible right nodes first, then search in the left nodes to match my incoming string

This is what I have so far

```
public Node search (String string)
   if(this.name.isEqualto.string)
     return this;
   else 
     if(this.next!=null)
       return this.getRight().search;
```

I am not sure how to make the code go back in the three and search left.

Comment: You shouldn't don't have `next` pointers in a BST. B stands for Binary, meaning two so each node has two pointers i.e. to the left and right child

Comment: The question still is unclear to me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there: to make your code search both subtrees, do not return from the search of `this.getRight` unless the item is found. Instead, search the left subtree, like this:

```
if (this.getRight() != null) {
    Node res = this.getRight().search(string);
    if (res != null) {
        return res;
    }
}
if (this.getLeft() != null) {
    return this.getLeft().search(string);
}
return null;
```